# playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Evaluation failed: cyclic object value when retriving dataLayer variable - Playwright-Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, google-datalayer, playwright-python

I'm using playwright with Python.

I'm trying retrieve the datalayer from a page with page.evaluate() from playwright .

**The error i get** :

playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Evaluation failed: cyclic object

**My code** :

```
datalayer = page.evaluate('''() => {
      
                   return JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)
        
                }''')
print(datalayer)
```

**In my return statement i've tried** :

- return window.dataLayer // return dataLayer => none object is returned in my print()
- List return dataLayer[0] => got the first element .

Is there a way to do this ?

EDIT :

what i need to get ( the full array + child objects ideally ) :

[image]

Thanks

***ANSWER :***

```
page.evaluate("() => dataLayer")
```

Comment: What do you need to get from there?

Comment: I've added a print screen of what i need in the question

Comment: The problem is not in playwight. The browser is not able to serialize that object. So you should try to solve as much as possible inside the evaluate and then return only the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the entire doc :

```
page.evaluate("() => dataLayer")
```